# getting entire data into collections using oracle PLSQL Bulk collect with limit clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulk-operations

I have one table called EMP with 140000 rows and I need , to keep entire data into collection .How to extend collection and load entire data into collection using "BULK COLLECT ..LIMIT" clause feature.

The below logic not providing required result , since data has  been overridden with new records.Please suggest me the logic.

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR c_get_employee IS 
      SELECT empno, 
             ename, 
             deptno, 
             sal 
      FROM   emp; 
    TYPE t_employee 
      IS TABLE OF c_get_employee%ROWTYPE INDEX BY inary_integer; 
    l_employee T_EMPLOYEE; 
BEGIN 
    OPEN c_get_employee; 

    LOOP 
        FETCH c_get_employee bulk collect INTO l_employee limit 300; 

        EXIT WHEN l_employee.count = 0; 
    END LOOP; 

    CLOSE c_get_employee; 

    FOR i IN 1..l_employee.count LOOP 
        dbms_output.Put_line (L_employee(i).ename 
                              ||'<-->' 
                              ||L_employee(i).sal); 
    END LOOP; 
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
      dbms_output.Put_line ('Unexpected error :- ' 
                            || SQLERRM); 
END;
```

Comment: *"The below logic is not giving required result"* . Life is generally easier for everybody if you define your expected output and explain how the actual output differs, instead of asking us to guess what the problem is.

Comment: Dear Team, I want to load entire data into collection and close the cursor.After that I want  to open collection and  use data for business  logic.

Answer (score 1):

You are exiting the loop too early. You need stop the fetch loop after the for loop and close cursor after that.

Also, as @APC pointed out, the exit condition should use count of fetched results instead of `NOTFOUND` on cursor. Otherwise, if the last fetch has lesser records than the fetch size, the `NOTFOUND` will be true and loop terminates incorrectly.

Try this:

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR c_get_employee IS 
      SELECT empno, 
             ename, 
             deptno, 
             sal 
      FROM   emp; 
    TYPE t_employee 
      IS TABLE OF c_get_employee%ROWTYPE INDEX BY binary_integer; 
    l_employee T_EMPLOYEE; 
BEGIN 
    OPEN c_get_employee; 

    LOOP 
        FETCH c_get_employee bulk collect INTO l_employee limit 3; 
        EXIT WHEN l_employee.count = 0;

        FOR i IN 1..l_employee.count LOOP 
            dbms_output.Put_line (L_employee(i).ename 
                                  ||'<-->' 
                                  ||L_employee(i).sal); 
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP; 
    CLOSE c_get_employee; 
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
      dbms_output.Put_line ('Unexpected error :- ' 
                            || SQLERRM); 
END;
```

Comment: Hi Gurwinder Singh , my requirement is , first i want keep entire data from cursor into collection.After that i want to close cursor and open my collection and want to business logic using this data which inside collection.

Comment: The bulk collect will replace the data in the variable in the next fetch. Besides, you shouldn't be reading the whole table in collection. If the number of records are small perhaps increase the fetch size to match the number of records.

Comment: I do agree with your point (The bulk collect will replace the data in the variable in the next fetch), but i want load entire data from cursor ,using "BULK COLLECT ...LIMIT"  feature  into collection .

Comment: @MastanSky so you want to load all the rows but you also want to limit them? It's not clear why you have the `limit` clause when you don't want to limit anything.

Answer (score 1):

> The below logic is not giving required result

Wild guess: you're only getting twelve rows. This is a familiar gotcha with LIMIT clause. This line is the problem:

```
EXIT WHEN c_get_employee%NOTFOUND;
```

You have fourteen records in EMP: The limit of 3 means you collect four sets of records. The last FETCH only collects 2 records. PL/SQL interprets this as `NOTFOUND`. The solution is to check the size of the collection:

```
EXIT WHEN l_employee.count() = 0;
```

---

> I want to load entire data into collection and close the cursor.After that I want to open collection and use data for business logic

That's not how BULK COLLECT ... LIMIT works. The point of the LIMIT clause is to, er, *limit* the number of records fetched at a time. We need to do this when the queried data is too big to handle in a single fetch. PL/SQL collections are memory structures held in the session's allocation of memory: if they get too big they will blow the PGA. (Definition of "too big" will depend on how your DBA has configured the PGA.)

So, if you have a small result set, ditch the LIMIT clause and populate the collection in a single fetch. But if you have sufficient data to require the LIMIT clause you need to include the business logic loop inside the fetch loop.